# how to install pgbench?

Tags: postgresql

I have postgreSQL 9.1 installed in my system. I want to run pgbench but the program is not istalled. I tried these but failed:

`apt-get install postgresql91-contrib`

no packet found

`apt-get install postgresql-contrib`

no packet found

`ln -s usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/bin/pgbench`

made the symlink but I get this error:

`Error: pg_wrapper: invalid command name`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?!

Comment: The version of ubuntu I am using is 14.04

Comment: you want postgres 9.1?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I want. PostgreSQL 9.1 was already installed when I got the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your mistake in:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql91-contrib
```

It should be:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

Or just run:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

And after that you can run:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/bin/pgbench
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get: `Package postgresql-contrib-9.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  postgresql-9.1`

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1`

Comment: really? Is it safe?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib`

Comment: `apt-get install postgresql-contrib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-contrib`

Comment: did you do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before?